# JVM crash on Eden space 100%

Tags: jvm, jvm-crash

I have a JVM crash every X weeks. The JVM is running JBoss AS 5.1. I have collected a lot of crash logs, all showing eden space 100% and concurrent mark-sweep generation total 3145728K (all of them same value!).
   I was browsing through similar cases, but can't match any. I am using Java 7 and just yesterday updated to newest release - and the problem came in the night again.
   Here' my JVM settings:

```
set JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Xms4g -Xmx4g -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX:NewRatio=3
set "JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Djboss.bind.address=0.0.0.0 -Djboss.server.log.dir=f:\log\jboss\node1"
set JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -XX:LargePageSizeInBytes=5m -XX:ParallelGCThreads=20 -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC 
set JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -XX:+PrintGC -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -XX:+PrintGCDetails -Xloggc:f:\log\jboss\node1\gc\gc.log -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=f:\dumps -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -XX:+PrintGCApplicationStoppedTime -XX:+PrintGCApplicationConcurrentTime -verbose:gc
```

And one of the crash logs:

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x00000000712f335e, pid=14532, tid=25004
#
# JRE version: 7.0_06-b24
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (23.2-b09 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# V  [jvm.dll+0x32335e]
#
# Core dump written. Default location: D:\jboss_node1\bin\hs_err_pid14532.mdmp
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
#

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x0000000000ddf800):  GCTaskThread [stack: 0x0000000000000000,0x0000000000000000] [id=25004]

siginfo: ExceptionCode=0xc0000005, reading address 0xffffffffffffffff

Registers:
RAX=0x000000077f87313b, RBX=0x0000000000de1c60, RCX=0x0000000000e0a398, RDX=0x000000000000003a
RSP=0x0000000004edee68, RBP=0x0000000000000001, RSI=0x0000000000000004, RDI=0x0000000000e0a398
R8 =0x0000000004edeea0, R9 =0x873148000000077f, R10=0x0000000000e0a398, R11=0x0000000000000060
R12=0x0000000000ea2f00, R13=0x0000000000e09f00, R14=0x000000000000009a, R15=0x0000000000ea3208
RIP=0x00000000712f335e, EFLAGS=0x0000000000010216

Top of Stack: (sp=0x0000000004edee68)
0x0000000004edee68:   00000000712df7e1 0000000000de1c60
0x0000000004edee78:   00000000712dfde3 0000000000000cf0
0x0000000004edee88:   0000000000000228 0000000000000398
0x0000000004edee98:   0000000000c23a20 0000000000000000
0x0000000004edeea8:   00000000000003ff 0000000000000000
0x0000000004edeeb8:   00000007a7e304c8 0000000000000000
0x0000000004edeec8:   0000000000000004 0000000000000000
0x0000000004edeed8:   0000000000000000 0000000000000000
0x0000000004edeee8:   000000000000004b 0000000000000000
0x0000000004edeef8:   0000000100000000 0000000000000000
0x0000000004edef08:   0000000000000000 0000000000000000
0x0000000004edef18:   0000000000000000 0000000000000000
0x0000000004edef28:   0000000000000000 0000000000000000
0x0000000004edef38:   0000000000000000 0000000000000000
0x0000000004edef48:   0000000000000000 0000000000000000
0x0000000004edef58:   0000000000000000 0000000000000000 

Instructions: (pc=0x00000000712f335e)
0x00000000712f333e:   18 4c 8b 49 18 49 83 79 10 00 49 8d 41 10 74 1b
0x00000000712f334e:   66 90 48 85 d2 74 14 4c 8b 08 48 ff ca 41 ff c3
0x00000000712f335e:   49 83 79 10 00 49 8d 41 10 75 e7 49 8b 49 10 49
0x00000000712f336e:   63 d3 49 29 52 30 49 89 4a 18 48 85 c9 75 11 49 


Register to memory mapping:

RAX=0x000000077f87313b is an unknown value
RBX=0x0000000000de1c60 is an unknown value
RCX=0x0000000000e0a398 is an unknown value
RDX=0x000000000000003a is an unknown value
RSP=0x0000000004edee68 is an unknown value
RBP=0x0000000000000001 is an unknown value
RSI=0x0000000000000004 is an unknown value
RDI=0x0000000000e0a398 is an unknown value
R8 =0x0000000004edeea0 is an unknown value
R9 =0x873148000000077f is an unknown value
R10=0x0000000000e0a398 is an unknown value
R11=0x0000000000000060 is an unknown value
R12=0x0000000000ea2f00 is an unknown value
R13=0x0000000000e09f00 is an unknown value
R14=0x000000000000009a is an unknown value
R15=0x0000000000ea3208 is an unknown value


Stack: [0x0000000000000000,0x0000000000000000],  sp=0x0000000004edee68,  free space=80763k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
V  [jvm.dll+0x32335e]


---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------

Java Threads: ( => current thread )
  0x0000000000dc1800 JavaThread "DestroyJavaVM" [_thread_blocked, id=23048, stack(0x0000000000fa0000,0x00000000010a0000)]
  0x0000000010b93000 JavaThread "Service Thread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=20900, stack(0x0000000011ae0000,0x0000000011be0000)]
  0x0000000010b91000 JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread1" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=20800, stack(0x0000000011940000,0x0000000011a40000)]
  0x0000000010b8d000 JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=26664, stack(0x0000000011080000,0x0000000011180000)]
  0x0000000010b88000 JavaThread "Attach Listener" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=33804, stack(0x00000000116b0000,0x00000000117b0000)]
  0x0000000010b87000 JavaThread "Surrogate Locker Thread (Concurrent GC)" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=21060, stack(0x0000000005460000,0x0000000005560000)]
  0x0000000010b06800 JavaThread "Finalizer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3844, stack(0x0000000011200000,0x0000000011300000)]
  0x0000000010b05800 JavaThread "Reference Handler" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=22540, stack(0x0000000010f50000,0x0000000011050000)]

Other Threads:
  0x0000000010afe800 VMThread [stack: 0x0000000010e40000,0x0000000010f40000] [id=28508]
  0x0000000010bae800 WatcherThread [stack: 0x0000000011c10000,0x0000000011d10000] [id=32268]

=>0x0000000000ddf800 (exited) GCTaskThread [stack: 0x0000000000000000,0x0000000000000000] [id=25004]

VM state:at safepoint (normal execution)

VM Mutex/Monitor currently owned by a thread:  ([mutex/lock_event])
[0x0000000000c2dd10] Threads_lock - owner thread: 0x0000000010afe800
[0x0000000000c2e290] Heap_lock - owner thread: 0x0000000058ad3000

Heap
 par new generation   total 943744K, used 875683K [0x00000006e0000000, 0x0000000720000000, 0x0000000720000000)
  eden space 838912K, 100% used [0x00000006e0000000, 0x0000000713340000, 0x0000000713340000)
  from space 104832K,  35% used [0x0000000713340000, 0x0000000715728d08, 0x00000007199a0000)
  to   space 104832K,  31% used [0x00000007199a0000, 0x000000071b9de200, 0x0000000720000000)
 concurrent mark-sweep generation total 3145728K, used 817374K [0x0000000720000000, 0x00000007e0000000, 0x00000007e0000000)
 concurrent-mark-sweep perm gen total 300520K, used 176172K [0x00000007e0000000, 0x00000007f257a000, 0x0000000800000000)

Card table byte_map: [0x0000000005e40000,0x0000000006750000] byte_map_base: 0x0000000002740000

Polling page: 0x0000000000be0000

Code Cache  [0x00000000010a0000, 0x00000000038b0000, 0x00000000040a0000)
 total_blobs=9848 nmethods=9127 adapters=669 free_code_cache=8557Kb largest_free_block=8332352

Compilation events (10 events):
Event: 56874.605 Thread 0x0000000010b91000 10237             java.awt.image.BufferedImage::<init> (955 bytes)
Event: 56874.620 Thread 0x0000000010b91000 nmethod 10237 0x0000000003893350 code [0x0000000003893560, 0x0000000003893de0]
Event: 57086.614 Thread 0x0000000010b8d000 10238             org.jboss.seam.util.Strings::split (53 bytes)
Event: 57086.652 Thread 0x0000000010b8d000 nmethod 10238 0x00000000026fdf10 code [0x00000000026fe120, 0x00000000026fee40]
Event: 57280.014 Thread 0x0000000010b91000 10239             com.myapp.details.tables.TableBuilder::getTransactionsList (249 bytes)
Event: 57280.228 Thread 0x0000000010b91000 nmethod 10239 0x0000000001b81410 code [0x0000000001b81780, 0x0000000001b84100]
Event: 57322.941 Thread 0x0000000010b8d000 10240             org.jboss.seam.deployment.DeploymentStrategy::postScan (56 bytes)
Event: 57322.960 Thread 0x0000000010b8d000 nmethod 10240 0x000000000210f310 code [0x000000000210f4e0, 0x000000000210f9f0]
Event: 57647.777 Thread 0x0000000010b91000 10241             java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentLinkedQueue::poll (85 bytes)
Event: 57647.782 Thread 0x0000000010b91000 nmethod 10241 0x0000000002d6a4d0 code [0x0000000002d6a620, 0x0000000002d6a7b8]

GC Heap History (10 events):
Event: 58388.223 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=5605 (full 13):
 par new generation   total 943744K, used 44796K [0x00000006e0000000, 0x0000000720000000, 0x0000000720000000)
  eden space 838912K,   0% used [0x00000006e0000000, 0x00000006e0000000, 0x0000000713340000)
  from space 104832K,  42% used [0x0000000713340000, 0x0000000715eff150, 0x00000007199a0000)
  to   space 104832K,   0% used [0x00000007199a0000, 0x00000007199a0000, 0x0000000720000000)
 concurrent mark-sweep generation total 3145728K, used 807707K [0x0000000720000000, 0x00000007e0000000, 0x00000007e0000000)
 concurrent-mark-sweep perm gen total 300520K, used 176171K [0x00000007e0000000, 0x00000007f257a000, 0x0000000800000000)
}
Event: 58437.185 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=5605 (full 13):
 par new generation   total 943744K, used 883558K [0x00000006e0000000, 0x0000000720000000, 0x0000000720000000)
  eden space 838912K,  99% used [0x00000006e0000000, 0x000000071331aa68, 0x0000000713340000)
  from space 104832K,  42% used [0x0000000713340000, 0x0000000715eff150, 0x00000007199a0000)
  to   space 104832K,   0% used [0x00000007199a0000, 0x00000007199a0000, 0x0000000720000000)
 concurrent mark-sweep generation total 3145728K, used 807707K [0x0000000720000000, 0x00000007e0000000, 0x00000007e0000000)
 concurrent-mark-sweep perm gen total 300520K, used 176171K [0x00000007e0000000, 0x00000007f257a000, 0x0000000800000000)
Event: 58437.234 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=5606 (full 13):
 par new generation   total 943744K, used 32647K [0x00000006e0000000, 0x0000000720000000, 0x0000000720000000)
  eden space 838912K,   0% used [0x00000006e0000000, 0x00000006e0000000, 0x0000000713340000)
  from space 104832K,  31% used [0x00000007199a0000, 0x000000071b981d98, 0x0000000720000000)
  to   space 104832K,   0% used [0x0000000713340000, 0x0000000713340000, 0x00000007199a0000)
 concurrent mark-sweep generation total 3145728K, used 809592K [0x0000000720000000, 0x00000007e0000000, 0x00000007e0000000)
 concurrent-mark-sweep perm gen total 300520K, used 176171K [0x00000007e0000000, 0x00000007f257a000, 0x0000000800000000)
}
Event: 58491.537 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=5606 (full 13):
 par new generation   total 943744K, used 871559K [0x00000006e0000000, 0x0000000720000000, 0x0000000720000000)
  eden space 838912K, 100% used [0x00000006e0000000, 0x0000000713340000, 0x0000000713340000)
  from space 104832K,  31% used [0x00000007199a0000, 0x000000071b981d98, 0x0000000720000000)
  to   space 104832K,   0% used [0x0000000713340000, 0x0000000713340000, 0x00000007199a0000)
 concurrent mark-sweep generation total 3145728K, used 809592K [0x0000000720000000, 0x00000007e0000000, 0x00000007e0000000)
 concurrent-mark-sweep perm gen total 300520K, used 176171K [0x00000007e0000000, 0x00000007f257a000, 0x0000000800000000)
Event: 58491.588 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=5607 (full 13):
 par new generation   total 943744K, used 39281K [0x00000006e0000000, 0x0000000720000000, 0x0000000720000000)
  eden space 838912K,   0% used [0x00000006e0000000, 0x00000006e0000000, 0x0000000713340000)
  from space 104832K,  37% used [0x0000000713340000, 0x000000071599c7d8, 0x00000007199a0000)
  to   space 104832K,   0% used [0x00000007199a0000, 0x00000007199a0000, 0x0000000720000000)
 concurrent mark-sweep generation total 3145728K, used 811608K [0x0000000720000000, 0x00000007e0000000, 0x00000007e0000000)
 concurrent-mark-sweep perm gen total 300520K, used 176171K [0x00000007e0000000, 0x00000007f257a000, 0x0000000800000000)
}
Event: 58522.240 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=5607 (full 13):
 par new generation   total 943744K, used 878193K [0x00000006e0000000, 0x0000000720000000, 0x0000000720000000)
  eden space 838912K, 100% used [0x00000006e0000000, 0x0000000713340000, 0x0000000713340000)
  from space 104832K,  37% used [0x0000000713340000, 0x000000071599c7d8, 0x00000007199a0000)
  to   space 104832K,   0% used [0x00000007199a0000, 0x00000007199a0000, 0x0000000720000000)
 concurrent mark-sweep generation total 3145728K, used 811608K [0x0000000720000000, 0x00000007e0000000, 0x00000007e0000000)
 concurrent-mark-sweep perm gen total 300520K, used 176172K [0x00000007e0000000, 0x00000007f257a000, 0x0000000800000000)
Event: 58522.288 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=5608 (full 13):
 par new generation   total 943744K, used 39161K [0x00000006e0000000, 0x0000000720000000, 0x0000000720000000)
  eden space 838912K,   0% used [0x00000006e0000000, 0x00000006e0000000, 0x0000000713340000)
  from space 104832K,  37% used [0x00000007199a0000, 0x000000071bfde670, 0x0000000720000000)
  to   space 104832K,   0% used [0x0000000713340000, 0x0000000713340000, 0x00000007199a0000)
 concurrent mark-sweep generation total 3145728K, used 813980K [0x0000000720000000, 0x00000007e0000000, 0x00000007e0000000)
 concurrent-mark-sweep perm gen total 300520K, used 176172K [0x00000007e0000000, 0x00000007f257a000, 0x0000000800000000)
}
Event: 58563.832 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=5608 (full 13):
 par new generation   total 943744K, used 878073K [0x00000006e0000000, 0x0000000720000000, 0x0000000720000000)
  eden space 838912K, 100% used [0x00000006e0000000, 0x0000000713340000, 0x0000000713340000)
  from space 104832K,  37% used [0x00000007199a0000, 0x000000071bfde670, 0x0000000720000000)
  to   space 104832K,   0% used [0x0000000713340000, 0x0000000713340000, 0x00000007199a0000)
 concurrent mark-sweep generation total 3145728K, used 813980K [0x0000000720000000, 0x00000007e0000000, 0x00000007e0000000)
 concurrent-mark-sweep perm gen total 300520K, used 176172K [0x00000007e0000000, 0x00000007f257a000, 0x0000000800000000)
Event: 58563.898 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=5609 (full 13):
 par new generation   total 943744K, used 36771K [0x00000006e0000000, 0x0000000720000000, 0x0000000720000000)
  eden space 838912K,   0% used [0x00000006e0000000, 0x00000006e0000000, 0x0000000713340000)
  from space 104832K,  35% used [0x0000000713340000, 0x0000000715728d08, 0x00000007199a0000)
  to   space 104832K,   0% used [0x00000007199a0000, 0x00000007199a0000, 0x0000000720000000)
 concurrent mark-sweep generation total 3145728K, used 816244K [0x0000000720000000, 0x00000007e0000000, 0x00000007e0000000)
 concurrent-mark-sweep perm gen total 300520K, used 176172K [0x00000007e0000000, 0x00000007f257a000, 0x0000000800000000)
}
Event: 58604.657 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=5609 (full 13):
 par new generation   total 943744K, used 875683K [0x00000006e0000000, 0x0000000720000000, 0x0000000720000000)
  eden space 838912K, 100% used [0x00000006e0000000, 0x0000000713340000, 0x0000000713340000)
  from space 104832K,  35% used [0x0000000713340000, 0x0000000715728d08, 0x00000007199a0000)
  to   space 104832K,   0% used [0x00000007199a0000, 0x00000007199a0000, 0x0000000720000000)
 concurrent mark-sweep generation total 3145728K, used 816244K [0x0000000720000000, 0x00000007e0000000, 0x00000007e0000000)
 concurrent-mark-sweep perm gen total 300520K, used 176172K [0x00000007e0000000, 0x00000007f257a000, 0x0000000800000000)

Deoptimization events (10 events):
Event: 43498.531 Thread 0x000000005287c800 Uncommon trap -83 fr.pc 0x000000000210f5f8
Event: 43498.534 Thread 0x000000005a47d800 Uncommon trap -83 fr.pc 0x000000000210c32c
Event: 45167.874 Thread 0x000000005a462800 Uncommon trap -10 fr.pc 0x00000000030a8960
Event: 45167.874 Thread 0x000000005a462800 Uncommon trap 23 fr.pc 0x0000000001b7d198
Event: 45203.070 Thread 0x0000000058287800 Uncommon trap -10 fr.pc 0x00000000030a8960
Event: 45203.070 Thread 0x0000000058287800 Uncommon trap 23 fr.pc 0x0000000001fdea7c
Event: 48744.132 Thread 0x000000005827d000 Uncommon trap -83 fr.pc 0x000000000282a3dc
Event: 50994.946 Thread 0x000000005a466000 Uncommon trap -12 fr.pc 0x0000000003878f08
Event: 52821.617 Thread 0x0000000057ff8800 Uncommon trap -83 fr.pc 0x0000000001221388
Event: 58031.170 Thread 0x0000000058278000 Uncommon trap -83 fr.pc 0x000000000362f5e8

Internal exceptions (10 events):
Event: 58461.635 Thread 0x0000000058ad3000 Threw 0x00000006f89fd940 at C:\jdk7u2_64p\jdk7u6\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp:1166
Event: 58462.823 Thread 0x0000000058287000 Threw 0x00000006f8df97a0 at C:\jdk7u2_64p\jdk7u6\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jni.cpp:742
Event: 58466.348 Thread 0x000000005882d000 Threw 0x00000006fcc6b340 at C:\jdk7u2_64p\jdk7u6\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jni.cpp:742
Event: 58484.610 Thread 0x0000000058ad3000 Threw 0x0000000707ffc958 at C:\jdk7u2_64p\jdk7u6\hotspot\src\share\vm\interpreter\linkResolver.cpp:805
Event: 58484.611 Thread 0x0000000058ad3000 Threw 0x000000070e95c960 at C:\jdk7u2_64p\jdk7u6\hotspot\src\share\vm\interpreter\linkResolver.cpp:805
Event: 58484.612 Thread 0x0000000058ad3000 Threw 0x000000070e962400 at C:\jdk7u2_64p\jdk7u6\hotspot\src\share\vm\interpreter\linkResolver.cpp:805
Event: 58495.612 Thread 0x0000000058278000 Threw 0x00000006e6195a58 at C:\jdk7u2_64p\jdk7u6\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp:1166
Event: 58570.956 Thread 0x0000000058279800 Threw 0x00000006e5c9a408 at C:\jdk7u2_64p\jdk7u6\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp:1166
Event: 58598.103 Thread 0x0000000058287000 Threw 0x00000007071a0b70 at C:\jdk7u2_64p\jdk7u6\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jni.cpp:742
Event: 58598.290 Thread 0x000000005882d000 Threw 0x00000007071f4418 at C:\jdk7u2_64p\jdk7u6\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jni.cpp:742

Events (10 events):
Event: 58590.621 Executing VM operation: RevokeBias done
Event: 58591.334 Executing VM operation: RevokeBias
Event: 58591.339 Executing VM operation: RevokeBias done
Event: 58601.224 Executing VM operation: RevokeBias
Event: 58601.228 Executing VM operation: RevokeBias done
Event: 58601.230 Executing VM operation: RevokeBias
Event: 58601.232 Executing VM operation: RevokeBias done
Event: 58601.367 Executing VM operation: RevokeBias
Event: 58601.371 Executing VM operation: RevokeBias done
Event: 58604.652 Executing VM operation: GenCollectForAllocation


Dynamic libraries:
0x000000013f660000 - 0x000000013f693000     C:\Java\jdk1.7.0_06\bin\java.exe
0x0000000077380000 - 0x0000000077529000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
0x0000000076ca0000 - 0x0000000076dbf000     C:\Windows\system32\kernel32.dll
0x000007fefd8b0000 - 0x000007fefd91c000     C:\Windows\system32\KERNELBASE.dll
0x000007fefdc30000 - 0x000007fefdd0b000     C:\Windows\system32\ADVAPI32.dll
0x000007fefde40000 - 0x000007fefdedf000     C:\Windows\system32\msvcrt.dll
0x000007feff4d0000 - 0x000007feff4ef000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\sechost.dll
0x000007fefe0a0000 - 0x000007fefe1cd000     C:\Windows\system32\RPCRT4.dll
0x0000000076dc0000 - 0x0000000076eba000     C:\Windows\system32\USER32.dll
0x000007feff4f0000 - 0x000007feff557000     C:\Windows\system32\GDI32.dll
0x000007fefdee0000 - 0x000007fefdeee000     C:\Windows\system32\LPK.dll
0x000007feff560000 - 0x000007feff629000     C:\Windows\system32\USP10.dll
0x000007fefc270000 - 0x000007fefc464000     C:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.7601.17514_none_fa396087175ac9ac\COMCTL32.dll
0x000007fefdbb0000 - 0x000007fefdc21000     C:\Windows\system32\SHLWAPI.dll
0x000007fefe070000 - 0x000007fefe09e000     C:\Windows\system32\IMM32.DLL
0x000007fefef60000 - 0x000007feff069000     C:\Windows\system32\MSCTF.dll
0x0000000073840000 - 0x0000000073911000     C:\Java\jdk1.7.0_06\jre\bin\msvcr100.dll
0x0000000070fd0000 - 0x00000000716ef000     C:\Java\jdk1.7.0_06\jre\bin\server\jvm.dll
0x000007fefa4e0000 - 0x000007fefa4e9000     C:\Windows\system32\WSOCK32.dll
0x000007feff2a0000 - 0x000007feff2ed000     C:\Windows\system32\WS2_32.dll
0x000007fefde30000 - 0x000007fefde38000     C:\Windows\system32\NSI.dll
0x000007fefa5c0000 - 0x000007fefa5fb000     C:\Windows\system32\WINMM.dll
0x0000000077540000 - 0x0000000077547000     C:\Windows\system32\PSAPI.DLL
0x00000000744b0000 - 0x00000000744bf000     C:\Java\jdk1.7.0_06\jre\bin\verify.dll
0x0000000074480000 - 0x00000000744a8000     C:\Java\jdk1.7.0_06\jre\bin\java.dll
0x0000000074420000 - 0x0000000074435000     C:\Java\jdk1.7.0_06\jre\bin\zip.dll
0x000007fefe1d0000 - 0x000007fefef58000     C:\Windows\system32\SHELL32.dll
0x000007feff070000 - 0x000007feff273000     C:\Windows\system32\ole32.dll
0x0000000074400000 - 0x0000000074419000     C:\Java\jdk1.7.0_06\jre\bin\net.dll
0x000007fefcfa0000 - 0x000007fefcff5000     C:\Windows\system32\mswsock.dll
0x000007fefd200000 - 0x000007fefd207000     C:\Windows\System32\wship6.dll
0x00000000743c0000 - 0x00000000743d1000     C:\Java\jdk1.7.0_06\jre\bin\nio.dll
0x000007fefc180000 - 0x000007fefc195000     C:\Windows\system32\NLAapi.dll
0x000007fef97d0000 - 0x000007fef97e5000     C:\Windows\system32\napinsp.dll
0x000007fefcf40000 - 0x000007fefcf9b000     C:\Windows\system32\DNSAPI.dll
0x000007fefa4f0000 - 0x000007fefa4fb000     C:\Windows\System32\winrnr.dll
0x000007fefcc20000 - 0x000007fefcc27000     C:\Windows\System32\wshtcpip.dll
0x000007fefb0a0000 - 0x000007fefb0c7000     C:\Windows\system32\IPHLPAPI.DLL
0x000007fefb080000 - 0x000007fefb08b000     C:\Windows\system32\WINNSI.DLL
0x000007fef9be0000 - 0x000007fef9be8000     C:\Windows\system32\rasadhlp.dll
0x000007fefafd0000 - 0x000007fefb023000     C:\Windows\System32\fwpuclnt.dll
0x0000000074470000 - 0x000000007447b000     C:\Java\jdk1.7.0_06\jre\bin\management.dll
0x000007fefd190000 - 0x000007fefd1a7000     C:\Windows\system32\CRYPTSP.dll
0x000007fefcd00000 - 0x000007fefcd47000     C:\Windows\system32\rsaenh.dll
0x000007fefd7e0000 - 0x000007fefd7ef000     C:\Windows\system32\profapi.dll
0x000007fefd710000 - 0x000007fefd71f000     C:\Windows\system32\CRYPTBASE.dll
0x0000000074330000 - 0x0000000074337000     C:\Java\jdk1.7.0_06\jre\bin\rmi.dll
0x0000000074340000 - 0x0000000074364000     C:\Java\jdk1.7.0_06\jre\bin\sunec.dll
0x00000000743b0000 - 0x00000000743bb000     C:\Java\jdk1.7.0_06\jre\bin\sunmscapi.dll
0x000007fefd960000 - 0x000007fefdac7000     C:\Windows\system32\CRYPT32.dll
0x000007fefd880000 - 0x000007fefd88f000     C:\Windows\system32\MSASN1.dll
0x0000000070d30000 - 0x0000000070ec3000     C:\Java\jdk1.7.0_06\jre\bin\awt.dll
0x000007fefdef0000 - 0x000007fefdfc7000     C:\Windows\system32\OLEAUT32.dll
0x000007fefb500000 - 0x000007fefb518000     C:\Windows\system32\DWMAPI.DLL
0x0000000074300000 - 0x000000007432a000     C:\Java\jdk1.7.0_06\jre\bin\dcpr.dll
0x0000000070f30000 - 0x0000000070f60000     C:\Java\jdk1.7.0_06\jre\bin\jpeg.dll
0x0000000074220000 - 0x0000000074259000     C:\Java\jdk1.7.0_06\jre\bin\kcms.dll
0x000007fef91e0000 - 0x000007fef9305000     C:\Windows\system32\DBGHELP.DLL

VM Arguments:
jvm_args: -Xrs -Dprogram.name=run.bat -Xms4g -Xmx4g -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX:NewRatio=3 -Djboss.bind.address=0.0.0.0 -Djboss.server.log.dir=f:\log\jboss\node1 -XX:LargePageSizeInBytes=5m -XX:ParallelGCThreads=20 -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+PrintGC -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -XX:+PrintGCDetails -Xloggc:f:\log\jboss\node1\gc\gc.log -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=f:\dumps -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -XX:+PrintGCApplicationStoppedTime -XX:+PrintGCApplicationConcurrentTime -verbose:gc -Dorg.jboss.resolver.warning=true -Dsun.rmi.dgc.client.gcInterval=691200000 -Dsun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval=691200000 -Djava.endorsed.dirs=d:/jboss_node1\lib\endorsed 
java_command: org.jboss.Main
Launcher Type: SUN_STANDARD

Environment Variables:
JAVA_HOME=C:\Java\jdk1.7.0_06\
PATH=C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Dell\SysMgt\oma\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Dell\SysMgt\idrac;
USERNAME=123456$
OS=Windows_NT
PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER=Intel64 Family 6 Model 47 Stepping 2, GenuineIntel



---------------  S Y S T E M  ---------------

OS: Windows NT 6.1 , 64 bit Build 7601 Service Pack 1

CPU:total 64 (8 cores per cpu, 2 threads per core) family 6 model 47 stepping 2, cmov, cx8, fxsr, mmx, sse, sse2, sse3, ssse3, sse4.1, sse4.2, popcnt, ht, tsc, tscinvbit

Memory: 4k page, physical 16763732k(1165800k free), swap 33525612k(18037992k free)

vm_info: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (23.2-b09) for windows-amd64 JRE (1.7.0_06-b24), built on Aug  9 2012 20:44:07 by "java_re" with unknown MS VC++:1600

time: Tue Aug 21 02:20:38 2012
elapsed time: 58655 seconds
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I note that you're using parallel GC and would perhaps switch that off to determine if it's exacerbating your problem. I would try:

1. reducing the GC threading (perhaps switch that off - do you need it?)
2. *downgrading* your JVM

In the meantime I would follow this advice and let Oracle know.

```
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
```

Comment: ok, I will try with switching off the gc threads. I also reported bug to oracle.